# Access RequestParameters inside Camel Freemarker ftl

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, freemarker

I am using Servicemix 4.4.1 that runs camel-freemarker version 2.8.0.fuse-06-11. In my ftl file, i need to use conditional routing based on whether a querystring exists in the request url or not.

For example:

if the url comes in appended with the query string "?wsdl" --> then the ftl should route to a different processor as opposed to the normal scenario. To achieve this, i have the following configuration in the ftl file.

```
<choice>
  <when>
<#list RequestParameters?keys as key>
 <#if key == '_wsdl'>
     <to uri="wsdlProviderProcessor">
 </#if>
</#list>                    
  </when>
  <otherwise>
     //do something else here
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

However my problem is that while building the compiling the ftl to create the route xml, i get the following exception.

Java backtrace for programmers:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression RequestParameters is undefined on line 216, column 40 in ftl/META-INF/spring/route-context.xml.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:135)
    at freemarker.core.BuiltIn$keysBI._getAsTemplateModel(BuiltIn.java:667)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
```

As i understand it is not able to get access to the RequestParameters variable. I tried using multiple approaches including variables like "request" & ${RequestParameters['_wsdl']} as indicated in the following links. However every time my code errors out with the same error message.

Any insights into the above issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no documentation to help, try:

```
<#list .data_model?keys as varName>
  ${varName}
</#list>
```

It's quite data-model-specific if it works and if returns all variables through. So if that fails, you can put a breakpoint at `freemarker.template.Template.process` to see what's passed to the template as the data-model.